# pem file permissions on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: windows, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am attempting to login to my box using my .pem file however I get the error

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0555 for './arete-server.pem' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: ./arete-server.pem
Permission denied (publickey).
```

chmod 400 doesn't work on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows and the best permissions I can give it is -r-xr-xr-x

Any idea how to get permissions to a point where I can use this pem file?

Comment: Keys aren't allowed to have any group or other ownership.  I don't know why chmod isn't working.  Did you try sudo?  FWIW you can try chmod go-rwx, or sudo chmod go-rwx

Comment: sudo using Bash on Ubuntu on Windows gives:  

sudo: unable to resolve host DESKTOP-4N3VUVG  

chmod go-rwx still gives -r-xr-xr-x

Comment: @ChristopherHoward -- if you're getting that message, your `hosts` file is not set up correctly; solve that problem, and I'd bet you'll be able to change the permissions using `sudo`.

Comment: @simon No longer getting the sudo error (thanks!)

However using sudo chmod 400 arete-server.pem still has permissions set as -r-xr-xr-x

Comment: @ChristopherHoward -- I lose my bet :(  What about the filesystem type?  If you're on FAT or NTFS (I think), you won't be able to set the permissions like that.  Could that be it?

Comment: @simon I think you are 100% right, NTFS seems to have issues with setting permissions using bash, I have resolved it by manually recreating the .pem file in the linux subsystem (Which could only be done after I resolved my sudo issues, So thank you VERY much :) )

Answer (score 41):

On WSL, chmod donesn't work on NTFS partitions used by Windows. You need to move your .pem file to a partition in Linux container (for example the home folder), then chmod 400 will work.

1. Navigate to a NTFS folder, example: cd /mnt/c/keyfiles
2. Move .pem file to your home folder: mv key.pem ~
3. Navigate to your folder: cd ~
4. Apply the permission: chmod 400 key.pem

Comment: After step 4. I was able to SSH using the key on my Linux container. Because I don't know much about how partitions apply permissions, one thing I noted is that copying your key back to your NTFS partition will not keep the permissions you set in the Linux container. I was able to use my key by keeping it inside of the Linux container where it had the correct permissions applied.

Comment: This work for me on Ubuntu, Thank you

Answer (score 13):

`sudo ssh -i mykey.pem ec2-user@ip` works for me

Answer (score 4):

use PowerShell:

1. icacls.exe key.pem /reset
2. icacls.exe key.pem /grant:r "$($env:username):(r)"
3. icacls.exe key.pem /inheritance:r

Comment: Only this powershell solution worked, no others - thank you!

Comment: Also I should add that `username` should be left literally as is because I keep coming back to this answer and unthinkingly adding my username

Comment: This is awesome, I have wasted my 3 days to try lots of solution but none worked. Only this one worked in Win 11

Answer (score 3):

On windows, follow the below command on PowerShell and not on cmd

```
$path = ".\Testkey1.pem"
# Reset to remove explict permissions
icacls.exe $path /reset
# Give current user explicit read-permission
icacls.exe $path /GRANT:R "$($env:USERNAME):(R)"
# Disable inheritance and remove inherited permissions
icacls.exe $path /inheritance:r
```

[image]
After that run command on cmd:

```
ssh -i file.pem username@ip-address
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you try to do this.

```
chmod 600 anyfile.pem
```

Comment: Since the question mentions a specific file, `./arete-server.pem`, perhaps your answer could be improved by referring to it?

Answer (score -1):

Manually re-created pem file in linux subsystem folder after resolving sudo issues

Files moved into system using explorer do not appear, neededd to be created using nano

Comment: `nano foobar.pem`

Paste the info into that, save

Answer (score -1):

Go to your File Explorer and right-click on the ex:keyname.pem file and go for show more options > then click on give access to > then go for remove access

come to your Ubuntu terminal or wsl

copy the file in the home directory

```
User@Ubuntu:~$ cp "/mnt/c/path_of_the_key_pair" ~
```

other related commands of your aws SSH client

note: these are mine just I changed the key names of these

```
User@Ubuntu:~$ chmod 400 MyKeyPair.pem

User@Ubuntu:~$ ssh -i "MyKeyPair.pem.pem" ubuntu@ec2-16-170-218-32.eu-north-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```